# TypeScript walk the SyntaxTree

Tags: typescript

I currently try to use the typescript compiler from javascript. I get an object of type `SyntaxTree` which I can print out as a string but how can I walk the tree and visit every token? Currently I stuck a bit because I cant really find any documentation about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you already have a TypeScript.SyntaxTree Object you are pretty close!

Al you have to do is create a custom class which extends TypeScript.SyntaxWalker or one of the classes which extends it like: DepthLimitedWalker or PositionTrackingWalker

So the class looks like this:

```
export class TSWalker extends TypeScript.PositionTrackingWalker {
}
```

And call syntaxTree.sourceUnit().accept(new TSWalker());
Now you can override functions like: public visitMemberFunctionDeclaration(node: TypeScript.MemberFunctionDeclarationSyntax) and do the stuff you want!
Other stuff you can override can be found here: http://typescript.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/compiler/syntax/syntaxVisitor.generated.ts
Note the above works with 0.9.5 but should still work on the typescript develop branch.

Comment: Thanks! The problem is when I try to inherit from TypeScript.PositionTrackingWalker I get everytime a javascript Runtime Error that Typescript is not defined strangly